# Switch LEDs with servo control signal / PWM

Tags: pwm, servo, remote-control

I have a RC receiver that produces a PWM signal for hobby servos (specs below). I would like to control some LED lighting with it. What are my options? I obviously do care about weight, like I do about functionality.

The setup is as follows:

[image]

The PWM specs are as explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_control -- 5V, 50 Hz, pulse width 1000 μs for OFF, 2000 μs for ON. I plan to use current-regulating LEDs rated 5 to 20 V as I don't need to dim them, but if a dimming option is available with output voltage e.g. 0 to 5 V, I'll happily switch to some common 3.1 V LEDs + resistors.

I feel like I cannot be the first one facing this issue, but I can't find any commercial solution, possibly because I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have more details on the LEDs?  Maybe a datasheet?  If they are already self-regulating, it might be hard to dim them.

Comment: connect a servo horn to a potentiometer shaft

Comment: @Aaron I don't need to dim them. I clarified this, I hope it's better now.

Comment: I'm confused then.  What do you mean by "control" for LEDs?  Just on/off?

Comment: @Aaron yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

I acutally found what I was looking for after some more googling. One such item is called [**Menace RCswitch**](https://menacerc.co.uk/product/rcswitch). I'm not sure how it's wired internally, but it seems it will do the trick just fine.

(Note that it's put between the powered device and V-, so it's supposed to switch the minus side of the device, not the plus side.)